# Sent attachment with SmtpClient loses its contentID

Tags: c#, email, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an in-line image via System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient. When sent, the image loses its content ID and cannot be referenced in the HTML body. Searching for this issue on google yields nothing, so what am I doing wrong?

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(); 
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

string contID = "Image@image.img";
Attachment attach = new Attachment("c:/image.png");
mail.Attachments.Add(attach);
attach.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
attach.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
attach.ContentId = contID;

mail.Body = "<htm><body><img src=3D\"cid:" + contID + "\"></body></html>";
mail.From = new MailAddress("from@doma.in");
mail.To.Add("to@doma.in");
mail.Subject = "Test";
smtpC.Send(mail);
```

And here's the attachment that gets sent in the email

```
----boundary_0_4a1cf86c-c96f-4498-a5a5-7b3e9b49357d
content-type: image/png; name="image.png"
content-transfer-encoding: base64
content-disposition: inline; filename=image.png

[base64 data here]
```

Comment: I guess, these should be same:  attach.ContentId = **contID**;

<img src=3D\"cid:" + **contentID** + "\">

Comment: They are the same (the second one came from another attachment I was messing with), but that's not the issue. The issue is that the Attachment loses its content ID when sent